# Magento issue - Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_File_Storage' not found

Tags: php, magento

I am transfering my customer and product information to a new install of magento and when importing with CSV im hit with this:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_File_Storage' not found in /home/wwwsmkd/public_html/wholesale/app/Mage.php on line 547

This is the code

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass); // Line 547
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this path

app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\File\Storage.php

Does **Storage.php** file exist or not?

If this file not exist then may be the issue with new magento installation.

Hope this helps you some how.